# Javascript Basic Logic - print each three and four cycle from 1 to n

Tags: javascript, logic

I want to see the output like

```
 [0, 1, 2]

 [3, 4, 5, 6]

 [7, 8, 9]

 [10, 11, 12, 13]

 [14, 15, 16]
```

...

recognize every three(a cycle) and four(b cycle) to do something.
I have only figure out some bad way I think like following:

```js
var arr = [];

function a(n) {
  var eachCycle = 7;
  var aCycle = 3;
  var bCycle = 0;
  arr.push(0);
  for (var i = 1; i < n; i += 1) {
    if (i % eachCycle === aCycle || i % eachCycle === bCycle) {
      if(i % eachCycle === aCycle) {
        // print three column 
      } else if(i % eachCycle === bCycle) {
        // print four column
      }
      console.log(arr);
      arr.length = 0;
    }
    arr.push(i)
  }
}
```

is there any good idea to improve this function for the output !?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
function a(n)
{
    // keep track of all the cycles
    var total = [];

    // hold values for the current cycle
    var temp = [];

    // cycle sizes
    var cycleSizes = [3, 4];

    // index of the current cycle
    var currentCycleIndex = 0;

    // iterate through numbers
    for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // push the value into the temp
        temp.push(i);

        // if the length of the temp array is the length we want for the current cycle then
        if(temp.length == cycleSizes[currentCycleIndex])
        {
            // save the cycle data
            total.push(temp);

            // reset the cycle
            temp = [];

            // change the cycle
            currentCycleIndex = currentCycleIndex ^ 1;
        }
    }

    return total;
}

a(9);

[
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8]
];

a(17);

[
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [10, 11, 12, 13],
    [14, 15, 16],
];
```